# Javascript slow to populate ActiveXObject Excel.Application

Tags: javascript, excel

I have an Array of up to 25,000 objects that I am iterating over and exporting to Excel using the code below. The export runs painfully slow and looks to take hours for the full 25,000 objects. The data put into Excel is actually more then the forename and surname shown below.

Is there a way of generating an Excel documents quicker? Or even a CSV file?

```
var xls = new ActiveXObject ( "Excel.Application" );
xls.visible = true;
var totalsSheet = xls.Workbooks.Add;
totalsSheet.Worksheets.Add;
totalsSheet.Worksheets(1).Activate;
totalsSheet.Worksheets(1).Name="Dinners";
for (var i = 0; i < filteredObjects.length; i++) {
    totalsSheet.Worksheets(1).Cells(i + 2, 1).value = filteredObjects[i].forename;
    totalsSheet.Worksheets(1).Cells(i + 2, 2).value = filteredObjects[i].surname;
}
```

Comment: did you try to set visible at the end only? In some environments this would speed up the process

Comment: @Sebas Yes, I've put the visible=true at the end and it still takes as long.

Comment: Is there a .loadFromCSV or similar in the worksheets methods? Javascript can't create file but maybe excel could take virtual datas to load an entire document?